# How to install ffmpeg 3.0 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, ppa, ffmpeg

ffmpeg 3.0 was released in February, it solves an important bug so I want to use it.

Is there any easy way to install ffmpeg on Ubuntu Wily, for instance a PPA?

What I tried:

- Xenial [only has 2.8.6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2), just [like Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ffmpeg).
- The static build at http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ are compiled without pulse support, and I did not manage to run it with ALSA
- The PPA https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media is only for Trusty, and advises against using it for other versions
- I tried compiling from source, for some reason the resulting ffmpeg records in much lower quality, videos are pixelated ([console output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15492756/)).

Comment: You could take a look here, it provides the ffmpeg binaries that use shared libs. It appears to install those libs to a non standard location so not to interfere with the default repo shared ffmpeg libs. https://launchpad.net/~djcj/+archive/ubuntu/hybrid

Comment: You should show your command and complete console output from the `ffmpeg` that you compiled.

Comment: @doug: https://launchpad.net/~djcj/+archive/ubuntu/hybrid/+files/ffmpeg_3.0-1~wily_amd64.deb looks promising but it says `Dependency is not satifiable: libkvazaar3`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Added.

Comment: Perhaps pastebin your actual command and then the full subsequent terminal output?

Comment: @andrew.46: Done, full console output link at the end of the question.

Comment: You have not modified the defaults for the output video. LordNeckbeard is the expert here but try the following and see if there is improvement, it is not lossless (which would be a choice) but should give better video quality if your system can keep up: src/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -framerate 10 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 test.mkv

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Your `ffmpeg` is missing support for libx264, so it is using the "mpeg4" fallback which has not-so-good defaults. If you want to re-compile see [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this as a working solution for 16.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

More information can be found [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/09/install-ffmpeg-3-1-ubuntu-16-04-ppa/).

Comment: **Godsend!** Works great on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution as of April 2016 is to compile by yourself.

The procedure is described at http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Be sure to run the procedure described at the "libx265" paragraph too, not doing it would result in bad quality video files.

Comment: There's now a way to update it easily via `apt` as per @mtasic's answer.